# How do I check public IP using Python or DDNS with Cloudflare

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

It's any way to check my public IP addres using Python? I have had an account on Cloudflare and VPS in a home (but dynamic IP). I need to update VPN IP'S before had an account on OVH and DDNS works after migration dose not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

requests:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://ifconfig.me')
print(response.text)
```

python 2:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://ifconfig.me')
print response.read()
```

python 3:

```
from urllib import request
response = request.urlopen('http://ifconfig.me')
print(response.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of websites online that offer simple APIs to check the IP address you're connecting from.

As an example:

```
➜ ~ curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json'
{"ip":"1.2.3.4"}
```

You can use a python library (like [Requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)) to call the API in python code.

```
# download requests with `pip install requests`

import requests
res = requests.get("https://api.ipify.org?format=json")

your_ip = res.json() # {"ip" : "1.2.3.4"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've created a simple docker image that allows you to keep you local ip in sync with Cloudflare AKA Cloudflare Dynamic DNS (DDNS)
check it out here:
https://github.com/marcelowa/cloudflare-dynamic-dns